# Give Menu a permanent url

Tags: php, html, permalinks

Just a simple question i cant seem to find the answer on google.

i got a file called `navigation.php`

I add the navigation via includes to my other php files as its easier. Now i get into trouble linking them together as it tries to access the file path twice.

is there a way to give my pages a permanent URL?

no code yet, as i cant find anything to try.

```
 <div class="masthead animated flipInX">
<nav>
  <ul class="nav nav-justified">
    <li class="active"><a href="../index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="php/about.php">The Family</a></li>
    <li><a href="php/adventure.php">Our Adventures</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Profil</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Edit: OK got it to work. As WAMP makes the www folder its root folder the absolute path didnt work. I had to remove my website from its folder straight onto the root directory (www) I guess that would do it unless there is a way to change the root directory?

Comment: what do you mean, "access the file path twice"? Your nav file is being included twice?

Comment: if im on the about.php page, and click again on about, other websites jsut refresh the page, but since my path is `php/about.php` it turns into `php/php/about.php`

Comment: Then you should use absolute urls: `href="/php/about.php"`.

Comment: thats the same i have in the code i posted above, right? or does the first / actually mean something? i thought its jsut a safety net

Comment: No, it actually means something. Without the "/" means, "relative to my current page" so it'll append the link to the current page. The "/" means "relative to the root of the site" (which is why it's an "absolute" path) so it'll remove everything after the domain and add the link to that.

Comment: that just broke everything. now it goes out of the folder into a non-existing php folder, and if i add the root folder  it adds the root folder twice

from here 
`http://localhost/petbook/index.php`

to here 

`http://localhost/php/about.php`

or if i add the root folder, then it does this
`http://localhost/petbook/petbook/php/about.php`

Comment: No. it's not just a safety net. `php/about.php` is a relative path, rooted in the script's CURRENT directory. `/php/about.php` is a local absolute path, rooted in the site's document root. `http://example.com/php/about.php` is a universal absolute, rooted at the top of the universe.

Comment: If you're mixing absolute paths and relative paths, then you have an ugly task ahead of you. if you want to use the SAME nav file, no matter where you are in your script, no matter what sub-directories you're in, YOU have to make sure that your nav script outputs appropriate paths for where the link should end up pointing.

Comment: wait so the reason `/php/about.php` ends up messing it up is because the `www` folder of wamp is considered as the root? anyway to change that?
////

ok got it localhost is my "server" therefor the "root" everything after that is the path, got it. unless i move my file out of their folder onto the localhost, there is no way of fixing my issue right now right?

Comment: Marc was right, if you want to write it as an answer i can mark it as helpful

Answer (score 0):

"Permanent url"? Do you mean you want to allow your file up and running on the server? if that's your case, then you should look for a server to host all your file. then you can access through url. Below are a free hosting server that you can look over
https://www.000webhost.com/

This website will allow you to hold your php file, and you can access those file through url link. Hope this will help.

Comment: i thought of a way offline as im not ready to rent a domain yet. just using wamp tbh.